# django detail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'

Tags: python, html, django

url.py

```
path('detail/<int:pk>', movie.views.detail, name='detail')
```

views.py

```
def detail(request, primary_key):
    moviedetail = get_object_or_404(movieinfo, pk=primary_key)
    return render(request, 'movie/detail.html', {
        'moviedetail':moviedetail
    })
```

moviehome.html

```
<a href="{% url 'detail' movieinfos.movie_id%}">
```

detail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'

Could you please help me?? How do i have to fix it??

Comment: You `detail` method should have `pk` as second parameter name, not `primary_key`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `path(..)` you defined a parameter `pk`:

```
path('detail/<int:pk>', movie.views.detail, name='detail')
```

So that means your `detail` method should have a parameter `pk`, *not* <s>`primary_key`</s>. You either should rename the parameter, or change the `path(..)` accordingly:

```
def detail(request, pk):
    moviedetail = get_object_or_404(movieinfo, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'movie/detail.html', {
        'moviedetail':moviedetail
    })
```